# Python remove last character of string if its a letter

Tags: python

How do I remove the last character of a string if its a letter.

e.g if I had the following strings.

```
my_string = 'ABC 1.1 A'
my_string2 = 'ABC 1.1 B'
my_string3 = 'DEF 1'
```

I would want `my_string = 'ABC 1.1'`, `my_string2 = 'ABC 1.1'`, and `my_strin3 = 'DEF 1'`

These strings are generated from DB so it would not be a manual process.

Comment: In your example you removed two characters (the letter *and* a whitespace before it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str.rstrip()`:

```py
import string
my_string = my_string.rstrip(string.ascii_letters + string.whitespace)
```

This will remove all letters and whitespace characters from the end of the string.

Comment: @hochl why did you remove `import string`?

Comment: @Ben: I added `import string` while hochl edited the post, so it got lost.

Comment: -1. This will remove the whole string if it's something like "ABC DEF", not just the last letter and preceding whitespace.

Comment: @Wooble: ... which I explicitly said in my answer.  Judging from the examples, I think this is what the OP wants.  If you really think this answer is not helpful, then we have different notions of helpfulness.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import string
if my_string[-1] in string.ascii_letters:
    my_string = my_string[0:-1].strip()
```